# Close a socket when all pending messages have been sent

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, concurrency

I have this method to write messages to a socket:

```
public void sendMessage(byte[] msgB) {
    try {
        synchronized (writeLock) {
            log.debug("Sending message (" + msgB.length + "): " + HexBytes.toHex(msgB));
            ous.write(HEADER_MSG);
            ous.writeInt(msgB.length);
            ous.write(msgB);
            ous.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Now a thread called **Bob** would like to close the socket at some undeterministic moment **X**, which means that there may still be threads waiting on `writeLock` to send their message, and there may even be one thread in the middle of writing it.

I can solve the latter by letting **Bob** acquire `writeLock` before closing the socket, but I could still lose messages that have not yet begun sending, because as far as I know `synchronized` is not fair, **Bob** could get the lock before some other thread that has been waiting longer.

What I need is that all calls made to `sendMessage` before **X** do their job normally, and calls made after **X** throw an error. How can I do this?

- Specifics: **Bob** is the thread reading from the socket's input stream and **X** is when a "close" message is received on that stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I could replace the synchronized block with a [ReentrantLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) set to be fair.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a single-threaded [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to perform writing of messages.  Sending threads simply attempt to "send" their message by calling `execute(Runnable)` or `submit(Callable)`.  Once you wish to stop sending messages you shut-down the `ExecutorService` ([`shutdown()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29)) causing subsequent calls to submit / execute to result in a `RejectedExecutionException`.

The advantage of this approach is that you only have one I/O bound thread and less lock-contention than if you have multiple threads waiting to write messages themselves.  It is also a better separation of concerns.

Here's a quick example that OO-ifies the problem a bit more:

```
public interface Message {
  /**
   * Writes the message to the specified stream.
   */
  void writeTo(OutputStream os);
}

public class Dispatcher {
  private final ExecutorService sender;
  private final OutputStream out;

  public Dispatcher() {
    this.sender = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    this.out = ...; // Set up output stream.
  }

  /**
   * Enqueue message to be sent.  Return a Future to allow calling thread
   * to perform a blocking get() if they wish to perform a synchronous send.
   */
  public Future<?> sendMessage(final Message msg) {
    return sender.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
      public Void call() throws Exception {
        msg.writeTo(out);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  public void shutDown() {
    sender.shutdown(); // Waits for all tasks to finish sending.

    // Close quietly, swallow exception.
    try {
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used my own method because I don't want to add another thread to a server system which already has hundreds, but upvoted anyway because it's technically the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an executor here.  Since each send message is synchronized (I am assuming on a commonly shared object) you can use thread confinement.

```
static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void sendMessage(byte[] msgB) {
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                log.debug("Sending message (" + msgB.length + "): " + HexBytes.toHex(msgB));
                ous.write(HEADER_MSG);
                ous.writeInt(msgB.length);
                ous.write(msgB);
                ous.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
public static void atMomentX(){
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

When finished another thread can invoke atMomentX();

From the javadoc the shutdown method says:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which
>   previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be
>   accepted.  Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut
>   down.

Comment: I used my own method because I don't want to add another thread to a server system which already has hundreds, but upvoted anyway because it's technically the correct way to do it.